# DOJO Dialog Submit with weird results

Tags: dojo, dialog

I am having an issue with the following code. The execute function executes not on the submit of the form (there is a button being created) but before the dialog even appears. The flow of the program is simply you click on a button and the dialog is supposed to be created. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
   theDialog = new Dijit.Dialog({});
   theDialog.attr("Class", "soria");
}
function createDialog(){
   theDialog.attr("title", "Add New");
   theDialog.attr("Content", buildContent());
   theDialog.attr("execute", alert('hello'));
   dojo.parser.parse(theDialog.parentNode);
   theDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: not sure why you would need to call parse.  That's only for declarative markup like <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button">... also, I'm not sure there is an execute attribute on Dialog.  Perhaps there is a method you could dojo.connect to.

Comment: The buildContent actually returns a string to put as the content which is html. There are some buttons within there that need to be parsed. This is more of a hack job because I want the dialog to look a specific way with a couple of grids and some buttons.I would add more function detail but the development laptop cannot be put on the network while at work. So I have to end up retyping everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is independent of Dojo. The arguments of a function are evaluated before calling the function.  Perhaps you meant to quote "alert('hello')" and pass the string?  Otherwise, the alert gets evaluated immediately.

Comment: Now there is an error that states this.execute is not a function. Any ideas?

Comment: nevermind, I did not look at your first response closely enough. Thanks for your help